# Plotting each Pandas Dataframe row as a separate plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have several lines of data store in a CSV file. I would like to iterate through each row and plot each row as a separate plot. After some research, it is looking like pandas would be the way to tackle this problem.

This is for Jupyter Notebook. I have tried reading in the CSV file directly, but find pandas much easier to work with. However, I am only pulling my y-values from the dataframe. I have defined a separate numpy array with my x-values.

For example, I have:

```
 x_values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
 my_data = pd.read_csv('example_data.csv')
```

In my data, I have the first column listed as "location" ranging from 1 to 20 miles. After that, I have 8 columns filled with values. I want to iterate through each row where I can create a graph for each of the locations. Because I am using subplot, would I need to convert the iterations as a numpy array? Would it be better to just read in the CSV file without using pandas?

```
 fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(4,3))
 ax1.plot (x_values, my_data) # would like this to loop for each row
```

I am able to slice the dataframe and manually create my graphs, but with 20 locations, a loop of some sort is ideal. I also have read through the power of pandas and would like to learn more so I can get my experience using it, so I would prefer to stick with pandas, but if not, any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can transpose and plot, e.g. `df.T.plot()`.

Comment: oops wrong thread!

Answer (score 0):

You can just transpose when plotting:

```
df.T.plot()
```

or when skipping the first column with a slice:

```
df[1:].T.plot()
```